# Removing Name from News Web Part

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, web-part, modern-experience

I am using News web part on a modern page.  I add a new News and I see it on my home page.  But I don't want my name to appear.  It has my new News but it has my name and date that I created the News.  Is there a way to hide or remove my name and date from the News web part modern site?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could deploy the spfx extension [react-script-editor](https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor)

Then add below CSS sytle to modern script editor web part:

```
<style>
.a_a_91bed31b.b_a_91bed31b{
display : none ;
}

</style>
```

Comment: Thank you.  Curious. Can the same method be done on premise?

Comment: Yes, this also works for on permise. This version is for Sharepoint on-premises: https://github.com/pnp/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor-onprem